# How to check ip address of an user and show different content in my webpage

Tags: javascript, .net, geolocation, ip-address

I want to show different content inside one particular div tag using javascript or any other better method, for the users/visitors of the United States.

***Update:***

Ok, now i see why SO is so reach in quality content. My apologies for not explaining he question properly.

My website is accessed globally,so there is a spelling difference in British English and American English.

For Eg: British English- Travellers , American English- Travelers

So i want to change the spellings according to the location of the user. 
I am new to this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Good to know. Do you have a particular problem with achieving this?

Comment: (1)google it. (2) ask here when u get stuck with solutions from googling.

Comment: Geolocation - there are a couple of services that offer that kind of API.

Comment: If older browsers are'nt an issue, HTML5 has a geolocation API that works pretty good in most browsers. On the other hand, what was the question again ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, i will check on the geolocation API. i have also updated the question. kindly have a look.

Comment: @t3hn00b thanks for the help. i will check on these APIs.

Comment: Your site is for **travellers**? Are you sure you want to do this based on ip address? If I travel to another country, then I'd be connecting to the site from that country and wouldn't want the language localised to my geographical location.

Comment: @rob i tried googling. couldnt find a good solution and the right keywords to search. i am really new in this area.

Comment: @Quentin ya the site is for travellers, its tripnest.com. your point is valid though. thanks. Can you suggest if we can use any other filter rather then using ip addresses.